# Overview effect on postgis polygon table

Tags: qgis, postgis

Is There a Way, with postgis and qgis, to reproduce the overview effect of tiff Raster on a polygon table in order to increase speed?
What if we could create simplified versions of this table,gathered under the same view.
Until now, i only play with different scale visibility on different simplified version of the table.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to achieve. Could you please expand on your question, clearly describing what you want to do?

Comment: On qgis, my postgis 50000 polygons table is taking too long to load or zoom for m'y users at small scales (from 1/50000 to 1/200000

Answer (score 1):

In QGis, The simplify geometry rendering option seems to answer my question. It uses the PostGIS snap_to_grid function according to scale.
In that way, the layer drawing is accelerated.